# How to disable Edge search from address bar?

Tags: search, microsoft-edge

It seems somewhere along the line Edge (claims to be 114.0.1823.67, June 29, 2023) completely removed the option to disable it. I thought it was there previously. I'll have to quit using the darn thing if it keeps sending local network requests or misspellings to DDG. Sad and annoying.

[Edge option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrfmg.png)

I already added value SearchSuggestEnabled (dword:0) to reg at Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge. No apparent effect.

Aside, but perhaps pertinent, I've also disabled Edge updates in every way mentioned on the interwebs anywhere, and seemed to have finally succeeded only by renaming the Edge Update App folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A screenshot would help identify what your trying to disable

Comment: I added a pic. It appears as a link: Edge Option above. I don't know how to get it to display inline here. Firefox has a flag to disable, as Chrome did at one time. Surely you know what "search from address bar" means. It is that incredibly annoying, invasive, privacy compromising feature added to all browsers a couple of years ago.